# Python- Taking columns from multiple .csv files and paste them into new .csv master file

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

SO here is the thing, I have 4 .csv files to which I want to copy one column from each of these 4 files and merge them into one single column as the first column of a new .csv master file. Then, repeat the same process again with another set of different columns and store it as a second column of the master file, and do it again at least 12 more times.

Here is my code so far:

CODE-

```
import os
import csv
import datetime as dt
from os import listdir
from os.path import join 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



#get the list of files in mypath and store in a list

mypath = 'C:/Users/Alan Cedeno/Desktop/Test_Folder/'
onlycsv = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if '.csv' in f]

#print out all the files with it's corresponding index

for i in range(len(onlycsv)):
print(i,onlycsv[i])

#prompt the user to select the files

option = input('please select file1 by number: ')
option2 = input('please select file2 by number: ')

#build out the full paths of the files and open them

fullpath1 = join(mypath, onlycsv[option])
fullpath2 = join(mypath, onlycsv[option2])

#create third new.csv file

root, ext = os.path.splitext(fullpath2)
output = root + '-new.csv'

with open(fullpath1) as r1, open(fullpath2) as r2, open(output, 'a') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    merge_from = csv.reader(r1)
    merge_to = csv.reader(r2)
    # skip 3 lines of headers
    for _ in range(3):
    next(merge_from)
    for _ in range(1):
        next(merge_to)
    for merge_from_row, merge_to_row in zip(merge_from, merge_to):
        # insert from col 0 as to col 0
        merge_to_row.insert(1, merge_from_row[2])
        # replace from col 1 with to col 3
        #merge_to_row[0] = merge_from_row[2]
        # delete merge_to rows 5,6,7 completely
        #del merge_to_row[5:8]
        writer.writerow(merge_to_row)
```

Any suggestions?

PLease let me know if the post needs formatting.

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do here? if you want to merge all csv to one as it is then it will be good.

```
with open(fullpath1) as r1, open(fullpath2) as r2, open(output, 'a') as fout:
   for line in r1:
      fout.write(line)
   for line in r2:
      fout.write(line)
   fout.close()
```